# Faults in Windows Updates Services and more on Windows 11

Tags: windows, windows-registry, windows-11, windows-update, services

My friend's been having issues with his computer when trying to update to 23H2. Initially this started with a "Something went wrong. Try to reopen Settings later." message. After digging around services.msc, he found out that the Windows Update service would not start together with a 1053 Error Code. (Changing the timeout duration in the registry didn't fix this.) These are the solutions him and I have tried since then to virtually no avail.

- Running batch scripts, registry files, lots of terminal commands from Microsoft Community Support we could find by googling to fix the service entries.

> This resulted in a duplicate Windows Update service appearing which actually started and got rid of the "Reopen Settings" message. However when trying to update we almost immediately got an 0x80248007 error inside Settings when trying to download the update, after trying some other similar community solutions we started getting a different 0x80070424. We found out that the Update Orchestrator Service couldn't run as well with the same 1053 Error.

- Running DISM and SFC.

> SFC never found any errors and DISM would not run, at all neither in online or offline mode.

- Running DISM with using a Windows 11 ISO as its source

> This didn't work.

- Updating Windows 11 to 23H2 by manually downloading and installing the update from the Microsoft Update Catalog online.

> After taking its sweet time this failed too.

- Trying to repair the system by installing Windows 11 *again* with an ISO we got from the Media Creation Tool, with the settings for keeping all apps and programs.

> This did update Windows 11 to 23H2, and got DISM working again. SFC started to find and fix some errors too.

In the end with the last mentioned solution, Windows Update and Update Orchestrator services still cannot start with the same error and we again get a "Try to reopen Settings later." message when trying to open the Windows Update tab.

We have not been able to find any more solutions on our own from this point, and I'm wondering if there *is* any hope besides doing a clean install. Maybe safe mode and the recovery environment have some tricks but I admit I'm not well-acquainted with either of those.

Any help and opinions are appreciated.

Comment: Your friend's computer seems to be in a bad shape. Try a [Repair Install Windows 11 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/repair-install-windows-11-with-an-in-place-upgrade.418/), but do that using the [Windows 10 2022 22H2 ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/software-download/windows10).

Comment: Thanks for reaching out so fast. The computer's sort of new and so has been on Win11 from the get go. Would an in-place upgrade repair still be possible with a Win10 ISO? And just so I can inform my friend, would doing this allow us to keep any apps and programs?

Comment: Sorry, a mistake - you should use Windows 11 22H2 ISO, which is more complicated to find.

Comment: Try [Windows 11 Download - How to Get the Windows 11 22H2 ISO File](https://www.easeus.com/system-to-go/download-windows-11-22h2-iso.html#2).

Comment: Given your post, the best thing I think here is to completely back up and install Windows fresh.

Comment: @harrymc Quick question, on the installer window there is an option about getting updates, drivers and optional features. Are we supposed to turn this option off?

Comment: You should not turn that off as drivers are important and optional updates do no harm

Comment: @Alucaius - That opinion controls if the installation environment will download the updates before installing or not, Windows Update, has absolutely nothing to do with that particular option

Comment: You already have the good drivers, don't set this option.

Comment: We "updated" to 22H2 and it doesn't seem to have done anything different. Still the same message in Settings and everything.